# Include loggroup name in the indexname for Lambda

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, kibana

I am streaming data from cloud watch logs to Elastic Search Cluster and I want the index pattern to include the log group. Below is the lambda code.

By Default -

```
var source = buildSource(logEvent.message, logEvent.extractedFields);
source['@id'] = logEvent.id;
source['@timestamp'] = new Date(1 * logEvent.timestamp).toISOString();
source['@message'] = logEvent.message;
source['@owner'] = payload.owner;
source['@log_group'] = payload.logGroup;
source['@log_stream'] = payload.logStream;
var x = source['@log_group'];
console.log('hello');
        // index name format: cwl-YYYY.MM.DD
var indexName = [
    'cwl-' + '- ' + timestamp.getUTCFullYear(),              // year
    ('0' + (timestamp.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),  // month
    ('0' + timestamp.getUTCDate()).slice(-2)          // day,
].join('.');
```

Change I need

```
var source = buildSource(logEvent.message, logEvent.extractedFields);
source['@id'] = logEvent.id;
source['@timestamp'] = new Date(1 * logEvent.timestamp).toISOString();
source['@message'] = logEvent.message;
source['@owner'] = payload.owner;
source['@log_group'] = payload.logGroup;
source['@log_stream'] = payload.logStream;
var x = source['@log_group'];
// index name format: cwl- myloggroup - YYYY.MM.DD
var indexName = [
    'cwl-' + x + '- ' + timestamp.getUTCFullYear(),              // year
    ('0' + (timestamp.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),  // month
    ('0' + timestamp.getUTCDate()).slice(-2)          // day,
].join('.');
```

**EDIT**

```
  var indexName = [
            'cwl-' + x + '-' + timestamp.getUTCFullYear(),              // year
            ('0' + (timestamp.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),  // month
            ('0' + timestamp.getUTCDate()).slice(-2),source['@log_group'].toString()          // day,
        ].join('.');
```

But with this change streaming of data fails. I am not sure what could cause this issue. 
[image]

hardcoded a text

```
// index name format: cwl-YYYY.MM.DD
var indexName = [
    'cwl-' + 'test' + timestamp.getUTCFullYear(),              // year
    ('0' + (timestamp.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),  // month
    ('0' + timestamp.getUTCDate()).slice(-2)          // day
].join('.');
```

[image]

Comment: Can you remove spaces from your index name and try?

Comment: Doesn't work, I added the edits section about my attempt in the question above.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Are you using ElasticSearch managed service or hosting on your own?

Comment: Can you check the image I have added, I added a console.log and it prints the right pattern, but I get failure during trial run. As soon as I remove my changes everything starts working and I start seeing logs in Kiabana

Comment: If you hard code indexName, do you see all documents in kibana?

Comment: check my attempt above added in the question, I added a "test" keyword and immediately I can see the index created in Kibana.

Comment: @Andrysha: See below answer, that's the reason it was not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you are putting the log group name in the index name, but if you want to filter log-based you on log group, you can filter using log sources name that is log-group.

[image]

There might be the case the ELK fail to create an index in case of append log-group name in the index due to naming convention, as AWS log-group normally include slash character.

**The rules for index names are encoded in MetaDataCreateIndexService 254. Essentially:**

```
Lowercase only
Cannot include \, /, *, ?, ", <, >, |, space (the character, not the word), ,, #
Indices prior to 7.0 could contain a colon (:), but that's been deprecated and won't be supported in 7.0+
Cannot start with -, _, +
Cannot be . or ..
Cannot be longer than 255 characters
```

Second thing, you are able to see with the hardcoded name because you are putting it on the right place as in first attempt you add the name in the day section.The purpose of datetime processor is to point documents to the right time based index based on a date or timestamp field in a document by using the date math index name support.

```
 var indexName = [
            'cwl-'+source['@log_group'].toString()+ '-' + timestamp.getUTCFullYear(),              // year
            ('0' + (timestamp.getUTCMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),  // month
            ('0' + timestamp.getUTCDate()).slice(-2),         // day,
        ].join('.');
```

or you can replace all special character in log-group name.

```
source['@log_group'].toString().replace(/[^A-Z0-9]+/ig, "-");
```

Comment: We need to make sure we use toLowercase too in case log group has uppercase letters as mentioned in the answer above.

Comment: In support of this, see the top Q+A for additional information: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/es-troubleshoot-cloudwatch-logs/